# Compress algorithm for sequence of numbers(long/int)

Tags: java, data-structures, struct, byte

I have a sequence of pairs of number. Each pair contains of 2 number `long` and `int`. Pairs are sorted in descending order by `int` value.  It can be represented as `Map<Long, Integer>`. (This map is sorted by by value in descending order)

There are more than 10 billions of `Map`, each `Map` may contain up to 40.000 pairs. But normally no more then 10.000 This data structure is a part of B-Tree index. This index takes too much disk space

I'm looking for a way to compress sequence of pairs to reduce the amount of disk space. `int` and `long` takes 4 + 8 = 12 bytes. But most of the `int` values are smaller and can be placed in 2-3 bytes. Most of the `long` values can be fit in 4-5 bytes.

I was thinking one of the options

1. Use special integer compression library like this (https://github.com/lemire/JavaFastPFOR). Used by Lucene to store its index. But I'm dealing with long not only with int, and my data is not sorted.
2. Naive approach. Use 1 byte as header for each pair, decode in 4 bits the number of bytes required for storing int, and the next 4 bits for storing number of bytes of long. For example if I have 2 small numbers < 255, I can place whole pair in 3 bytes, header, 1 byte for int and 1 byte for long.
3. Maybe usual gzip compression may be better than naive approach.

Comment: Is there no relation between the long and the integers? or between the maps? or is it just random numbers with more random numbers? Are there any ways you could group them, for example some of the maps only contain small numbers that could be stored as shorts etc.

Comment: The long and the int are mapped to each other, long is the key and the int is the value. The map itself is sorted by value. There is no relations between Maps, I think some of the maps may contain only short numbers but I don't know it before putting something into the map

Comment: There's a technique for compressing integer (int and long) values using a 7-bit encoding scheme. I've seen it used in many places. See [Variable-length quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) for a description.